# Javascript table age range filter

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created a table that contain employees information. I want to filter the table by `gender` and `age`. I create the filter for the `gender`, but the filter for the `age`. I had hardtime to find a solution for it. For example the filter i want to do is to find employees between two number, like all employees between age 23 and 30. here is my code.

```
export default class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      employees: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.employeesTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      // Meteor.subscribe('employees');
      const employees = Employees.find().fetch();
      this.setState({ employees });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.employeesTracker.stop();
  }

  renderEmployeesListItems() {
    return this.state.employees.map(employee => {
      return (
        <tr key={employee._id}>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>{employee.email}</td>
          <td>{employee.age}</td>
          <td>{employee.gender}</td>
          <td>{employee.city}</td>
          <td><Link className="link button" to={`/employee-detail/${employee._id}`}>EDIT</Link></td>
          <td><button className="button pointer" onClick={() => Employees.remove({_id: employee._id})}>DELETE</button></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  // --------------------------
  //Gender Filter
   myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("genName").value;
    filter = input;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }       
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select id="genName" onChange={this.myFunction.bind(this)}>
          <option value="">All Genders</option>
          <option value="M">Male</option>
          <option value="F">Female</option>
        </select>
        <p>Minimum age:</p>
            <input type="text" id="min" name="min"/>
        <p>Maximum age:</p>
            <input type="text" id="max" name="max"/>
        <table id="myTable" className="employeeTable">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
            <th>GENDER</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
            {this.renderEmployeesListItems()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this kind of filtering when user inputs data, you should use [React State](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), and the best way to integrate it today is using [hooks](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

In the state, you will not store `employees` as you did (which is only the result of a minimongo query to fetch the whole database), but `employeesToDisplay`. This will avoid the Html parsing in `myFunction`.

After some linting using state, your code should look like something like this :

```
//Gender Filter
myFunction() {
  var filter = document.getElementById("genName").value;
  // best is to get the input from context (look into `this` with console.log here)

  // assuming that filter is exactly what you are looking for in your database : 
  this.setState({
     employeesToDisplay: Employees.find({gender: filter}).fetch()
  })
}
```

Since state is reactive, your list will be updated as the gender is selected, with a rendering of the database elements that correspond to the query.

To do a query on the age of employees, refer to [the mongoDB documentation on queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) to build a request like :
`Employees.find({age: {$gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge}}).fetch()` that you will use to store the data to display in the state

Comment: Thank you for you explaination. I just have one question. I have to add employeesToDisplay in this.state as an array right? like the employee in the state.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how to do it